# Silverlight Style control

Tags: silverlight

I have added a check box in silverlight style.

```
    <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="Add to Template" x:Name="chkAllDelimited" Checked="chkAllDelimited_Checked" Unchecked="chkAllDelimited_Unchecked"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="false" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

How to get this x:Name="chkAllDelimited" control in the code behind?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Embedded inside a style as is you can't. An option you do have is adding an OnLoad event to the checkbox which would fire in your code behind, where you could then cast the sender to a CheckBox object and access it, store it in a local variable, or whatever you'd like to do with it.

Comment: Any example of this?